# Derivation of distance formula to isosurface of a scalar field.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality, vectors, taylor-expansion

I'm trying to understand derivation of approximated formula for closest distance from Inigo Quilez' article: [distance estimation](http://iquilezles.org/www/articles/distance/distance.htm) (Section "The maths") but it's hard to me to follow his logic.

He shows formula for upper limit of closest distance defined on scalar field $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, from given point $\vec{x}$ to the isosurface $f = 0$.

[image]

He says:

> Let's call that closest red point $\vec{x} + \vec{\epsilon}$, such that $\vec{\epsilon}$ is the vector going
>   from the yellow to the red one. What we are after here is $|\vec{\epsilon}|$, the
>   length of $\vec{\epsilon}$, which is the distance from the $\vec{x}$ to the
>   isoline/isosurface. In this setup, since $\vec{x} + \vec{\epsilon}$ is in the 0-isoline, we
>   clearly have
>   $$
>   f(\vec{x} + \vec{\epsilon}) = 0
> $$
>   Let's assume we are pretty close to the shape, meaning, that $|\vec{\epsilon}|$ is
>   small. Then, we can expand $f(\vec{x} + \vec{\epsilon})$ in its Taylor's decomposition
>
> $$
> f(\vec{x} + \vec{\epsilon}) = f(\vec{x}) + \vec{\nabla} f(\vec{x})\cdot \vec{\epsilon} + O(|\vec{\epsilon}|^2)
> $$
>
> where the dot (·) means dot product, as usual (remember that both the
>   gradient and $\vec{\epsilon}$ are vectors here).

That's pretty clear. Then he says:

> If we were close enough, indeed,
>   then we could just use this linear approximation of f and say that
>
> $$
> 0 = |f(\vec{x} + \vec{\epsilon})|\approx |f(\vec{x}) + \vec{\nabla} f(\vec{x})\cdot \vec{\epsilon}| \tag{1}\label{1}
> $$

This is almost clear. The only thing that I don't understand is why is there absolute value? Shouldn't the equation be without absolute value?

The next part is even more unclear to me:

> meaning that
>
> $$
> 0 \ge|f(\vec{x})| - |\vec{\nabla} f(\vec{x})\cdot \vec{\epsilon}| \ge |f(\vec{x})| - |\vec{\nabla} f(\vec{x})| \cdot |\vec{\epsilon}|
> $$
>
> the first inequality being due to the triangle inequality, and the
>   second one to the basic properties of dot product.

Triangle inequality would give us (based on $\eqref{1}$):

$$
0 \approx |f(\vec{x}) + \vec{\nabla} f(\vec{x})\cdot \vec{\epsilon}| 
\Rightarrow
0 \le |f(\vec{x})| + |\vec{\nabla} f(\vec{x})\cdot \vec{\epsilon}|
\Rightarrow
0 \ge -|f(\vec{x})| - |\vec{\nabla} f(\vec{x})\cdot \vec{\epsilon}|
$$

Am I right? I don't understand why, in Inigo's article:
$$
0 \ge|f(\vec{x})| - |\vec{\nabla} f(\vec{x})\cdot \vec{\epsilon}|
$$
?

Also I don't get the second inequality:
$$
|f(\vec{x})| - |\vec{\nabla} f(\vec{x})\cdot \vec{\epsilon}| \ge |f(\vec{x})| - |\vec{\nabla} f(\vec{x})| \cdot |\vec{\epsilon}|
$$
Which basic properties of dot product say that:
$$
- |\vec{a}\cdot \vec{b}| \ge - |\vec{a}| \cdot 
|\vec{b}|
$$
$$
|\vec{a}\cdot \vec{b}| \le |\vec{a}| \cdot |\vec{b}|
$$
?

(I'm assuming that on the right hand side we have vector norms and the dot is ordinary multiplication - nothing else makes sens to me here)

Can someone give me simple proof of this inequality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some help of the author of the article himself, I finally fully understand the derivation. Here is the full story:

Having a scalar field $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ we want to find distance from given point $\vec x$ to the isosurface $f = 0$. 
Lets assume that $f(\vec x + \vec e) = 0$, for some vector $\vec e$, then what we are searching for is $|\vec e|$ - the length of vector $\vec e$.

We know that if $\vec x + \vec e$ is close to point $\vec x$, then we can approximate $f(\vec x + \vec e)$ by its 1-st order Taylor series approximation:
$f(\vec x + \vec e) \approx f(\vec x) + \vec\nabla f \cdot \vec e$ 
then (by assumption $f(\vec x + \vec e) = 0$):

$0 = f(\vec x + \vec e) \approx f(\vec x) + \vec\nabla f \cdot \vec e$

Lets assume that approximation is accurate:

If $0=f(\vec x) + \vec\nabla f \cdot \vec e$ , then equivalently:

$|0|=|f(\vec x) + \vec\nabla f \cdot \vec e|$ , which is the same as: $0=|f(\vec x) + \vec\nabla f \cdot \vec e|$

Based on triangle inequality $|a + b| \le |a| + |b|$, for any real $a$ and $b$, and letting:

$a = p + q$

$b = -q$,

for any real $p$ and $q$, we can derive the following inequality:

$|p + q - q| \le |p + q| + |-q|$

$|p| \le |p + q| + |q|$

$|p| - |q| \le |p + q|$ which is the same as $|p + q| \ge |p| - |q|$

Case A) Consider:

$p = f(\vec x)$

$q = \vec\nabla f \cdot \vec e$

so we have:
$0=|f(\vec x) + \vec\nabla f \cdot \vec e| \ge |f(\vec x)| - |\vec\nabla f \cdot \vec e| \implies 0 \ge |f(\vec x)| - |\vec\nabla f \cdot \vec e| \implies |\vec\nabla f \cdot \vec e| \ge |f(\vec x)| $

Case B) Swap $p$ an $q$ from case A:

$p = \vec\nabla f \cdot \vec e$

$q = f(\vec x)$

so we have:
$0=|\vec\nabla f \cdot \vec e + f(\vec x)| \ge |\vec\nabla f \cdot \vec e| - |f(\vec x)| \implies 0 \ge |\vec\nabla f \cdot \vec e| - |f(\vec x)| \implies |f(\vec x)| \ge |\vec\nabla f \cdot \vec e|  $

From case A and case B we can conclude that:
$|f(\vec x)| = |\vec\nabla f \cdot \vec e| $

From definition of dot product ($\vec a \cdot \vec b = |\vec a| |\vec b| cos \theta$):

$|\vec\nabla f \cdot \vec e| \le |\vec\nabla f| |\vec e|$, so we could write:

$|f(\vec x)| = |\vec\nabla f \cdot \vec e|  \le |\vec\nabla f| |\vec e|$

$|f(\vec x)| \le |\vec\nabla f| |\vec e|$

$\frac {|f(\vec x)|}{|\vec\nabla f|} \le |\vec e|$

Which is exactly the result that Inigo Quilez came with.